# Proving an Identity Linear Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let V be an n-dimensional vector space, and let $0 ≤ m < n$. If W is an $m$-dimensional subspace of V and X is an ($n-m$)-dimensional subspace of V, show that there exists a linear transformation $T: V{\longrightarrow}V$ such that ker (T) = W and Im (T) = X.

I don't really know how to start the proving. I can't grasp the idea of (n-m)-dimensional subspace. I wish you can give me clues on how can I approach this problem. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I'm guessing your $k$ should be an $m$? 
If you can grasp the idea of an $m$ dimensional subspace, you might manage to grasp the idea of an $\ell$ dimensional subspace. Just set $\ell = n-m$ ;)

Comment: I've edited the $k$. Thank you for the notice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose a basis $w_1,\dots,w_m$ in $W$ and extend it to a basis $w_1,\dots,w_m,\ u_1,\dots,u_{n-m}$ of $V$.
Also choose a basis $x_1,\dots,x_{n-m}$ of $X$.

Finally, consider the linear extension of the mapping
$$w_i\mapsto 0\,,\\
u_j\mapsto x_j\,.$$

Comment: Is this also sufficient to prove the existence of the linear transformation $T: V {\longrightarrow}V$?

Comment: Yes, it's constructed.

Comment: I'm somewhat lost, can you elaborate how?

Comment: Name $T$ the linear extension of the mapping I gave in my answer. What are the kernel and the image of $T$?